# Cannot get accessibility label/value for components in Mac app in XCTest

Tags: xctest

I am trying to access the elements in the UI Testing XCTest. I can able to access the accessibility label and values in the XCTest for some UI elements which is preset automatically. But some of the elements are found without the accessibility label or values. I want to know in what are the cases the accessibility label or values should not be preset or we cannot get the values in UI Testing?

I know one case. If the element is drawn in the drawRect method, we cannot access the UI component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessibility labels will generally be set automatically for UI elements with text or values, like buttons, labels, text fields and sliders.

When you're writing UI tests, it's best practice to use the `accessibilityIdentifier` of an element instead of the `accessibilityLabel`.

You should set an `accessibilityIdentifier` on each view you want to be accessible to your UI tests. No views have preset `accessibilityIdentifiers`, so you will be in complete control.

```
@IBOutlet let signInButton: UIButton!
...
signInButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "signInButton"
```